# Typescript collect classes belongig to the same module

Tags: build, typescript

I'm looking for a way to do this in the build process, with something, that is preferably available as a `gulp` plugin:

**A.ts**

```
module Test {
  export class A {
    //...
  }
}
```

**B.ts**

```
module Test {
  export class B {
    //...
  }
}
```

And with some tool create an uncompiled (still ts not js) output, where everything that belongs to the module `Test` is put in the same file like this:

**Output.ts**

```
module Test {
  export class A {
    //...
  }

  export class B {
    //...
  } 
}
```

Is this possible? If so, what tool is capable to do this?

I'm not interrested in solutions like "Oh you just need to read the first line, split it whitespace, then get these pieces...", I could do that, but I would like to find a tool which can confidently do this, without accidentaly breaking the semantics of the code.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

> I could do that, but I would like to find a tool which can confidently do this, without accidentaly breaking the semantics of the code

This tool does not exist. Also automatic ordering even in the absence of this tool (i.e. your *existing* semantics) is a problem and therefore I don't recommend internal modules anyways : https://github.com/TypeStrong/atom-typescript/blob/master/docs/out.md

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! I read the document you linked, it explained why `--out` is bad, but doesn't really offer a good alternative. I'm struggling with a very simple thing: source (1 class /  file - lots of files), tests (also a lots of files, depends on some sources), and also packaging the sources (make it easy for others to use it, this is what I tried to ask), for a pure ts project (no browser or node dependencies). Are there any best practices/recommendations on this? I'm feeling like I'm fighting on too many fronts here.

Comment: `no browser or node dependencies` > What's your runtime then?

Comment: currently node/commonjs (without anything node specific).

Comment: I dont' know a tool which makes exactly what you want but I guess e.g. http://typedoc.io/ uses the typescript API to go through all files and find all occurances of a module (and the included classes).

Comment: @bali182 just compile with `--module commonjs` and use `import/require` then

Comment: I have a lots of very small files, imagine an `Iterator` interface with a `next()` and `hasNext()` method for example. I wouldn't like to toss all of these into a single file, beacuse it would make development much harder, and I also wouldn't like to make the user `require` or `import` all these files. But during the build process, it would be very useful, to produce a ts file, which contains all of these, and the user (mainly the tests now) could `import` them from this single ts file. Have you some suggestions on how should I proceed?